# pointer based linked list gives segmentation error

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include "AirlineReservationSystem.h"
struct test{
    int num;
    test* tNext;
};

int main()
{
    test* a;
    a = new test;
    a->num = 8;
    a->tNext = new test;
    test* ptr = a;
    ptr = ptr->tNext;
    ptr->num = 9;
    cout << ptr->num;
    ptr = a;

    cout << ptr->num;

    while ( ptr->tNext != NULL){
        ptr = ptr->tNext;
    }

    cout << ptr->num;

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to understand here why this code gives a segmentation error. Disregard the include at the start, It does nothing.

I am very very very new at this and trying to understand pointers and linked lists better and make some practice yet i am unable to see what i am doing wrong.

Program itself prints the first two couts but crashed at while statement which means there must be some problem with it, if someone could explain to me what that problem really is and what i am missing, it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You never explicitly set to `NULL` the `next` pointer of the last element.

Comment: Don't forget to clean up your "mess". Uhm... I meant memory.

Comment: I thought it automatically pointed to NULL. If that isn't the case, then what does it point to?

Comment: @user3812398 This is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialized `ptr->num = 9`, but you have not initialized `ptr->tNext` to anything.

Now let's examine the following piece of code:

```
while ( ptr->tNext != NULL){
    ptr = ptr->tNext;
}
```

Iteration #1:

- Most likely `ptr->tNext != NULL`, so you enter the loop and set `ptr = ptr->tNext`.
- Now `ptr` is most likely pointing to an invalid memory address.

Iteration #2:

- `ptr` is most likely pointing to an invalid memory address.
- Therefore, `ptr->tNext` would most likely yield an illegal memory access.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the second test, you do not initialize the pointer member in the struct.

This means that it points to some random memory address which is not a test instance (although I heard that some compilers will automatically make it point to NULL, never seen this in action though). Mostly the memory that is reserved for the `struct` is not cleared by default, so any content that was there remains "in the `struct`" until you assign it with something else.

If you don't assign it a new value the application will break when trying to dereference the memory.

So to fix this:

```
struct test{
    test() : tNext(NULL) {} // ADD THIS AND ...
    ~test() { if(tNext) delete tNext; } // ADD THIS AND ...
    int num;
    test* tNext;
};

int main()
{
    test* a;
    a = new test;
    a->num = 8;
    a->tNext = new test;
    test* ptr = a;
    ptr = ptr->tNext;
    ptr->num = 9;
    cout << ptr->num;
    ptr = a;

    cout << ptr->num;

    while ( ptr->tNext != NULL){
        ptr = ptr->tNext;
    }

    cout << ptr->num;

    delete a; // ADD THIS

    return 0;
}
```

The first line is a constructor that sets the pointer to NULL which will prevent the pointer to point to random memory. The second line is the destructor which will clean up your nested structure recursively.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is desired because your code will exit from the `while` giving `segmentation fault` as your `ptr->tNext!=NULL` condition is not met at the last node also. So for the last node the ptr is set with a garbage value and hence when `ptr->tNext!=NULL` is executed, it gives segmentation fault error.

To avoid this, add the following line after `ptr->num = 9;`

```
ptr->tNext = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Probably you are missing initialization of tNext to NULL. 
Try changing your definition to:

```
struct test{
    int num;
    test* tNext;
    test():num(0),tNext(NULL) {}    // contructor initializing the members to default values
};
```

(2) You dont know if ptr is NULL or not inside while condition and in that case it is likely to give segmentation fault. Add null check on ptr in while () as well like this:

```
 while (ptr && ptr->tNext != NULL){   // ptr->tNext is executed only when ptr is valid
    ptr = ptr->tNext;
}
```